# How to integrate Test Manager and Bloodhound

Tags: trac, bloodhound

I followed, https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TestManagerForTracPlugin and 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIi3QMT0rT4), and installed a) Trac Generic Class b)Trac Generic Workflow c)Test Manager  in order.

I am trying to enable the components in the following order:
a) Trac Generic Class b)Trac Generic Workflow c)Test Manager

But, it shows blank page,  when I am enabling Trac Generic Workflow Component.

Any guidance on integrating Test Manager and Bloodhound would be highly appreciable!

Comment: Best place to start is to look in the [logs](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracTroubleshooting#ChecktheLogs).

Comment: Dear RjOllos, any model base.ini and trac.ini to use testmanager with bloodhound, please!